# LeafletJS map not displaying properly. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

[image]

Im using a certain JS framework which has it's own theme. Dont know if this is affecting LeafletJS.

How do I fix this? I want a normal working LeafletJS map.

**Temporary Solution:**

I noticed that this LeafletJS Maps displays properly when you minimize browser then maximize it again.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Probably you did not import leaflet.css that is the reason you see the map like this

Comment: Same here, I have imported `.css` file, I'm in `vue` with `webpack`.

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you try to create the Map (javascript) object before the div is created.

See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4835 and 
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-invalidatesize